# Debian can't mount partition or external hd

Tags: debian, filesystems, mount

I have recently installed a copy of Debian 7/Gnome in a partition along with Windows 7.

Even though I am the sole user of this computer, during the installation two accounts have been created: a root with administrative privileges and a second one for myself as regular user.

I am currently experiencing issues in obtaining access to external file systems. Although the system detects the *Windows 7* partion, I can't seem to mount the partition successfully, as I click on the icon as regular user, the following message is displayed:

> Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
>   Unprivileged user can not mount NTFS block devices using the external
>   FUSE library. Either mount the volume as root, or rebuild NTFS-3G with
>   integrated FUSE support and make it setuid root. Please see more
>   information at http://tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#unprivileged

so my second step was to fire up the terminal and type `sudo mount -a` and now the only message I get as I click on the icon is:

> Not Auhorized

The same thing happens when I plug in my external hard drive. I get the same issues. How do I mount successfully these file systems? Is there a way for the system to mount automatically, possibly even at start up if external file systems are detected?

Comment: In Debian to use `sudo` you have to add your user to the `sudoers` file. You can also `su -` or login as root to mount your device manually.

Comment: @YoMismo already did that.

Comment: And couldn't mount the drive? what error messages did you receive?

Comment: @YoMismo all the errors I have encountered are reported in my question.

Comment: Those errors display "unprivileged" and "unauthorized". You still get those same errors when `mount` is launched from root?

Comment: @YoMismo yes, I open the terminal, use sudo to mount then back to the file manager and I get the Not Authorized error.

Comment: But you can access the drive and files from root, right?

Comment: @YoMismo maybe not, because if I gain root privileges and navigate to /mnt direcory it is empty.

Comment: If you are using ntfs-3g you need "FUSE", make sure you have it installed. You should `mount -t ntfs /dev/yourdrive /mnt` if no error is received you should be able to access your drive through /mnt as root. According to Debian doc you should add the line `/dev/sda1 /mnt/windows ntfs-3g rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0002,fmask=0003 0 0` to your fstab (modifying your sdX and mount point) to have the mount automated.

Comment: I'm sorry mount type should be `ntfs-3g` instead `ntfs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue and editing '/etc/fstab' worked for me.

I had my ext hdd in fstab included like this:

`/dev/sdb1       /media/usb0     auto    rw,user,noauto  0       0`

Deleting whole line helped.